# How to change field value in database onclick button using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this code which displays information from the database in a table with `order_id` in every row. Now when I click on id, a modal appears with 3 options:
`Delete`, `Update` and `Disable row`.

How can I use one of these buttons to change value in the database where `if $_customer['order_id'] = order_id then order_status = 1`?

```
echo "<td align='center'  span style='font-weight:bold;'> <a   href = '#' data-toggle = 'modal' data-target = '#action'>".$f_customer['order_no']."</a></td>";
echo "<td>" .$f_customer['first_name']."</td>"; 
echo "<td>". $f_customer['last_name']."</td>";
echo "<td>". $f_customer['address']."</td>";
echo "<td>". $f_customer['driver_no']."</td>";
echo "<td>". $f_customer['d_time']."</td>";
echo "<td>". $f_customer['no_ofppl']."</td>";
```

Comment: bind a function to the Buttons and use Ajax Request to update ur table

Comment: I tried many times but no luck, how to take order_id value from table and send it using ajax?

Comment: i suppose ur `order_id` is 'order_no'. u have to bind with onclick there to open the button Display. this way u can update the function of the Buttons with the id

Comment: I'm going to try but the problem is there is a button first to open modal which has 3 buttons, so its not direct!

Comment: then you will have to put the order id somewhere the modal knows to fetch it from when submitting the ajax call - e.g. a hidden field, javascript variable, data-attribute of an existing element. Anywhere you can rely on really.

Comment: as @ADyson said. bin e.g.: `open_modal('order_id')` then in the function just just Display the modal and for example Change the functions of the Buttons to `delete('order_id_from_before')` . if u dont know how to. just use a `<Input>` and just Change the value. Then on DeletePress just read value from the Input . do ur Action -> and then Close modal + update the table. If this makes sense to u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as explained in the comments.

-1 open the modal with an order id ( PHP )

```
print '<div onclick="open_modal(\''.$f_customer['order_no'].'\')">'.$f_customer['order_no'].'</div>';
```

-2 jquery

```
function open_modal(order_no){
 // Change value of INPUT
 // Display Modal
}
```

-3 Modal
 Display all 3 Buttons here.

```
<Input type="hidden" Name="modal_order_id" id="modal_order_id" value="" />

<div onclick="modal_func_delete()">delete</div>
<div onclick="modal_func_update()">update</div>
<div onclick="modal_func_disable()">disable</div>
```

-4 jquery

```
function modal_func_delete() {
  // get id from INPUT
  // DO AJAX DELETE
  // execute function rebuild_table
  // Close Modal
}
```

-5 jquery

```
function rebuild_table() {
 // clean table Content with html('')
 // AJAX all rows from table.
 // Append new lines
}
```

U only Need 1 AJAX.php if u sent Parameters to it, so ur script knows what to do when ist triggert with different Parameters.

```
function modal_func_delete() {
{
    new Ajax.Request('AJAX.php',
    {
        method:'post',
        parameters:{q_input: $('.modal_order_id').val(), q_type: 'delete'},
        cache: false,
        onSuccess: function(transport)
        {
            jQuery('.debug').html(transport.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

and ur AJAX.php can pick it up with

```
if($_POST['q_type']=='delete')
{
// EXECUTE DB DELETE
}
```